# using environment variable in the perl script

Tags: perl, shell, variables, environment

I am running a perl script which execute the shell command as :

```
system ("bsub xyz +OPTIONS_GATE=$GATE")
```

here `$GATE` is my environment variable. When I execute the script. It gives the error

```
"No arguments supplied for option group OPTIONS_GATE instance".
```

How to deal with this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. If finds many errors, including this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$GATE` in a double quoted string will be considered a Perl variable. If you want to use an environment variable, you can use the `%ENV` hash:

```
system ("bsub xyz +OPTIONS_GATE=$ENV{GATE}")
```

Alternatively, you can escape the dollar sign so Perl does not treat `$GATE` as a Perl variable:

```
system ("bsub xyz +OPTIONS_GATE=\$GATE")
```

Or use a single quoted string, which does not interpolate variables:

```
system ('bsub xyz +OPTIONS_GATE=$GATE')
```

Note that if you had used

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

It would have told you about this error. `strict` would have said:

```
Global symbol "$GATE" requires explicit package name
Execution of script.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

And `warnings` would have said:

```
Name "main::GATE" used only once: possible typo at script.pl line 12.
Use of uninitialized value $GATE in string at script.pl line 12.
```

When you do not use `use strict; use warnings;` your errors are not removed, they are only hidden from you, so that they are harder to find. Therefore, always use these two pragmas.

Comment: The shell will still interpolate without escaping, so the best is actually `system('bsub xyz +OPTIONS_GATE="$GATE"')` or `system('bsub', 'xyz', '+OPTIONS_GATE='.$ENV{$GATE})`